# Does the N64 version of Vigilante 8 2nd Offense have a cheat menu?

Tags: nintendo-64, vigilante-8-2nd-offense

According to the [IGN guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/vigilante-8-second-offense/N64_Cheats), if you went to the Game Status screen and pressed <kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> buttons, it would open up a password entry screen where you could use various codes to unlock characters among other things.

I do not remember being able to do this on my N64 with this game, and I cannot replicate this on the RetroArch emulator with the Mupen64Plus core. I know there were other versions of the game released on PS1 and Dreamcast, with minor differences between them.

Does this cheat menu exist in the N64 version, or did it only exist on the PS1 or Dreamcast versions?